# Error when trying to use markup extension

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a small window that I am trying to load when my application starts. Here is the (loose) XAML:

```
<ctrl:MainWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls">
<Grid>
    <ctrl:ConnectionStatusIndicator/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Resx ResxName=MyApp.MainDialog, Key=MyLabel}"/>
</Grid>
</ctrl:MainWindow>
```

Notice the custom control called ConnectionStatusIndicator. The code for it is:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Controls
{
    public class ConnectionStatusIndicator : Control
    {
        public ConnectionStatusIndicator()
        {
        }

        static ConnectionStatusIndicator()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ConnectionStatusIndicator),
                                                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ConnectionStatusIndicator)));
            IsConnectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsConnected", typeof(bool), typeof(ConnectionStatusIndicator), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            set { SetValue(IsConnectedProperty, value); }
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsConnectedProperty); }
        }

        private static DependencyProperty IsConnectedProperty;
    }
}
```

Now, here is where it gets weird (to me, at least). With the XAML as it appears above, my application will build and run just fine. However, if I remove the following line:

```
<ctrl:ConnectionStatusIndicator/>
```

or event move it one line down, I get the following error:

> Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}Resx'.'
>   Line number '13' and line position '33'.

What is really strange to me is that, if I replace ConnectionStatusIndicator with another custom control from the same assembly, I get the error. The other custom control is very similar, but has a few more properties.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Shouldnt the namespace be :CNC.UI.Controls in Xaml ?

Comment: What is this`{Resx ResxName=MyApp.MainDialog, Key=MyLabel}`?

Comment: Something I've been bitten by before, was that the designer likes to act up if the dependency property isn't public. Try marking `IsConnectedProperty` public, see if it does anything to help.

Comment: @CSharpie - Sorry, I edited the code to make it as brief as possible and missed a spot. I corrected the code in my question

Comment: @Hamlet - Resx is a markup extension we use for localization. I got it from here [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Resx` markup extension belongs to the `Infralution.Localization.Wpf` namespace but also does something a bit hackish and attempts to register itself to the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` xml namespace to allow developers to use it as `{Resx ...}` instead of having to declare the namespace in XAML and use the extension with a prefix `{resxNs:Resx ...}`.

I believe that if you clean up your solution and possible delete your *.sou file the project will build as expected, but a sure way to solve this will be to add an `xmlns` declaration for  `Infralution.Localization.Wpf` and use the extension with the xmlns prefix:

```
<ctrl:MainWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:Infralution.Localization.Wpf;assembly=Infralution.Localization.Wpf">
    <Grid>
        <ctrl:ConnectionStatusIndicator/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{loc:Resx ResxName=MyApp.MainDialog, Key=MyLabel}"/>
    </Grid>
</ctrl:MainWindow>
```

Also, for anyone interested, the "hack" is in these lines in the localization library:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Infralution.Localization.Wpf")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "Infralution.Localization.Wpf")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2008/xaml/presentation", "Infralution.Localization.Wpf")]
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I tried adding the namespace already, but never used it. Thanks!

Comment: @Adi Lester , How to use this (Resx) in other(other than Shell/MainWindow) xaml files of the application. I couldn't find the syntax even the example provided is for MainWindow. How about the other views of application which may present under separate project ?

Comment: @kamlendra I'm not an authority in regards to the extension and haven't worked with it for quite a while, but I don't think its usage is any different for other views/user controls.